# Vim-Markdown-Folding plugin error BufEnter E117

Tags: vimrc, folding, error, filetype-markdown, plugin-pathogen

[Inspired by Drew NEIL's](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/how-to-fold/) course and the 'nested-folding' feature for Markdown files, I've installed the [`Vim-Markdown-Folding` plugin](https://github.com/msprev/vim-markdown-folding), on my [Vim (`:version`)](http://pastebin.com/PY4fz1rC). The GitHub directory was copied into the `~/.vim/bundle` directory (as required by the `pathogen` plugin) with:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/msprev/vim-markdown-folding.git
```

Then I added the required

```
let g:markdown_fold_style = 'nested'
```

line into my `.vimrc`-file as described in the [`:help markdown-folding-configuration`](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding/blob/master/doc/markdown-folding.txt) file and got this wired error:

```
Error detected while processing BufEnter Auto commands for "<buffer=1>":
E117: Unknown function: mdfolding#foldtextupdate
```

when opening, saving, or even jumping into the (Vim-)window of any markdown file. Otherwise everything seems to work fine. However, every time the error occurs I have to confirm the reading and I really would like to settle any other potential complications.

Comment: looks like the plugin is not correctly installed

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Thank you :) The GitHub directory was copied into the `~/.vim/bundle` directory as required by the `pathogen` plugin with: `git clone https://github.com/msprev/vim-markdown-folding.git`. Do I have made some mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A bit of investigation

After finding the function in [source file](https://github.com/msprev/vim-markdown-folding/blob/2cd611f75a1cdf57c16c761c5f61aa8c3a42f94d/autoload/mdfolding.vim), with these lines preceding it:

```
if !has('python')
    echo "Error: Required vim compiled with +python"
    finish
endif
```

And installing the plugin (my Vim is built without python), I can easily get the same error:

```
Error detected while processing BufEnter Auto commands for "<buffer=1>":
E117: Unknown function: mdfolding#foldtextupdate
```

So `:echo has('python')` probably returns 0 for you, because your Vim either doesn't have python support at all or has only python3 support.

By the way, the authors of the plugins should use [`:echoerr`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aechoerr) for such cases, or users might ignore important error messages.

#### Plugin version

Please do keep in mind that **you did not install the original version** of the plugin. What you installed is actually a fork of Drew Neil's plugin -- it seems to try to optimize performance of folding, but also requires Vim with python support.

#### You can:

- use [original version](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding) of the plugin, which doesn't require python (your link to documentation points to this repository, actually):

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding.git
  ```
- change your Vim setup (if you really need this plugin)
- report upstream about the issue, maybe fixing it requires only adding check for `python3` feature (e.g., `if !has('python') && !has('python3')`), the author should know better anyway

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) (1) I don't understand the first bullet point. Since I've installed/use exactly the "original version of the plugin", why do I need python at all? (2) How could I install the python support [(python is installed)](http://pastebin.com/stGqJJyc). NB: here my [Vim `:version` output](http://pastebin.com/PY4fz1rC).

Comment: (3) Is it possible to show me the terminal command for installing the "original version of the plugin, which dosen't require python"? (In which case you may ignore point (2) above.)

Comment: @alex, added `git clone` command to the post. Your question uses `msprev/vim-markdown-folding`, which is a fork of `nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding`.

Comment: THANK YOU : ) It works. Could you please add a comment like: "Please do keep in mind that **you did not installed the original version** of the plugin. You installed actually a fork of Drew Neil's plugin -- which requires additionally python."